# Angular6: Bootstrap Module Components while Lazy-Loading

Tags: angular

**Explanation**

I have a secondary module that provides a shared logic/view (for simplicity, adds a footer in this example) for inner modules.

The structure is as follows:

- app.module

  - container.module

    - inner1.module
    - inner2.module

In `app.routing`, the module `app` lazy loads to `container` module as such:

```
  {
    path: 'inner1',
    loadChildren: 'app/container/container.module#ContainerModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'inner2',
    loadChildren: 'app/container/container.module#ContainerModule'
  },
```

While `container.routing.ts` selects the correct component:

```
  {
    path: 'inner1',
    component: Inner1Component,
  },
  {
    path: 'inner2',
    component: Inner2Component,
  }
```

And `container.module` bootstraps its own component:

```
  bootstrap: [
    ContainerComponent
  ]
```

Where `container.component.html` has a `router-outlet` and a footer:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>
   // Stuff here
</footer>
```

Now
**The Problem**

When the route is `inner1`, `container.component` is never really activated and the footer never shows. It seems that the `router-outlet` of `app.component.html` is showing directly the contents of `inner1.component.html`.

**Objective**

`app.module` router to show `container.component` contents in its outlet, and `container.module` router to show `inner1.component` in `container.component`'s outlet.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you wish to accomplish but maybe this will be of use to you: The ability to use multiple router outlets: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/

Comment: @jetset sorry if this wasn't that clear, but the objective is to have the module `app` router to show `container.component` contents in its outlet, and `container.module` router to show `inner1.component` in `container.component`'s outlet.